# Convert class object to class index

Tags: c#, class

```
Class Person {
  int Id 
  string Name 
  string Address 
  // etc 
}
```

instead of accessing it like Person.Id, Person.Name, Person.Address. I want to access it via index just like Person['Id'], Person['Name']. Is there any codegen or linq conversion for this.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: for datastruct comparision

Comment: @PaulWhite you don't need an indexer to compare structures. In fact `for datastruct comparison` doesn't explain what you actualy want to do - the *object* implements IComparable and Equals. If you only wanted to compare structures, you could use those. Are you trying to find field value differences perhaps? Merge differences? Treat lots of data as if they were DataTable or DataFrames? DataTables are available since .NET 1.0. Python-style dataframes are [a new addition](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-dataframe/)

Comment: This feels like an X/Y problem

Comment: Explain us what do you really want to do

Comment: To answer the written question, you can use the [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#fast-access-to-net-fieldsproperties) library to quickly and easily access properties using reflection. An indexer won't make structure comparison (whatever that means) easier though

Comment: I guess a manual implementation of an [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) is out of the question?

Comment: Or a manual implementation of [IComparable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.8) or [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Json.NET`'s `JObject` class

```
Person p = new Person() { Id = 1, Address = "A", Name = "B" };
var obj = JObject.FromObject(p);
Console.WriteLine(obj["Id"]); //1
```

Comment: Is there other option? I'm not allow to add nuget items. im using 3.5

Comment: @PaulWhite you haven't explained what you want yet, and .NET 3.5 isn't supported for quite some years now. *All* supported OSs have 4.5.2 or later, the oldest supported version. `for datastruct comparison` doesn't explain anything - objects implement `IComparable` for that

Comment: I don't know why is people upvoting this answer honestly

Comment: As for `I'm not allow to add nuget item` then you can't use .NET period - a *lot* of core libraries are provided as NuGet packages. You simply *can't* write *any* .NET software, except the simplest, without NuGet. Whoever made that policy probably doesn't understand what .NET is.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not true at all for .Net 4.8.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure C# implementation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "test",
            Address = "tost"
        };

        Console.WriteLine(person["Id"]);
        person["Id"] = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(person["Id"]);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this);
        }

        set
        {
            this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1
>
> 5

**Important note:**

I would never recommend to use this in a production environment, if you want to use an handly implemented system, atleast you should handle types and properties extractions to avoid consuming more memory than needed and exceeding overheads.

Comment: There's no need to use reflection *inside* the concrete object. Outside the object, reflection is useful but expensive. There are libraries that cache the type and property descriptors to minimize the cost

Comment: Yes, I would never do that, but anyway this is a basic example of the implementation

Comment: this is what i need but im having error on GetValue and SetValue

Comment: If you are using fields you must change GetProperty to GetField

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection and indexers:

```
public class ExampleClass{

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            var properties = typeof(ExampleClass)
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.Name == name && property.CanRead)
                    return property.GetValue(this, null);
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("Can't find property");

        }
        set {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason for reflection *inside* the concrete type

Answer (score 0):

An indexer won't make data comparison any easier. I suspect the *real* question is how to handle data in C# the same way Python's DataFrames work. ADO.NET provides the DataTable class since .NET 1.0. It's meant more for database processing than data analysis, altough it does support operations like searching, merging and diffing.

For data anlysis, the new Microsoft.Data.Analysis package provides the [DataFrame](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-dataframe/) class.

That said, to read properties by name, you'll have to use Reflection, an expensive operation. One way to make this cheaper is to cache type and property descriptors. Instead of writing the code yourself though, you can use Marc Gravel's [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#fast-access-to-net-fieldsproperties) library that does just that. With this, you can create a TypeAccessor or ObjectAccessor type and read properties by name, eg :

```
var wrapped = ObjectAccessor.Create(obj);
string propName = // something known only at runtime 
Console.WriteLine(wrapped[propName]);
```

If you want to read from multiple objects, you'll need a TypeAccessor :

```
var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(type); 
string propName = // something known only at runtime 
while( /* some loop of data */ )
{ 
  accessor[obj, propName] = rowValue; 
}
```

The library isn't that big. If you aren't allowed to use NuGet packages, you could copy the code into your project.